# NSCollectionview didSelectItemsAt not getting called second time

Tags: macos, nscollectionview

I am developing mac os application where I am using NSCollectionview where at some point I need to get data of particular index where i have implemented didSelectItemsAt delegate method,
Now issue is when I click on cell first time it will get executing that didSelectItemsAt  and then after I have clicked on another cell it is not executed that method, whenever I reload
reload view controller and click on any cell it executed didSelectItemsAt but not for the second time.

Below delegate method which i have implemented.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>){

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below line at the end of your logic in the didSelectItemsAt method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>){
        collectionView.deselectAll(nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be better to write it like this:

```
collectionView.deselectItems(at: indexPaths)
```

Comment: Why? What would be the benefit of this approach over e.g., the accepted answer?

Comment: @Jeremy Caney This method generates less assembly code, about 30 lines less. According to the development documentation, the goal of this method of operation is more specific. However, when I use this method, the program has crashed. Because it does not happen sometimes, so I have not found the reason

Comment: Oh, that’s all really interesting! Given how useful that is, would you mind editing it into your original answer? Very curious about the source of the crash, and whether other people are experiencing it.